# sqlite, inserting column data from one table to another

Tags: sqlite

I am new to sql and I have the following problem,
In sqlite, I am interested to find how to add data from one table to another where data from column x should correspond to data in column Y.

For example lets say my table (`Eruptions`) consists of 4 columns:

```
Eruption Number (PK) 
Volcano Number 
Volcano name
start date
```

I have created a new table called Eruptions_since_2000 and interested in adding values from the original table to the new table.

The new table (`Eruptions_since_2000`) consist of 4 empty columns:

```
eruption_number(PK,unique,not null) 
volcano_number 
volcano_name 
start_date
```

In my fist step I have added the data from Eruption number (from original table) to eruption_number in new table with the following code:

```
INSERT INTO Eruptions_since_2000 (Eruption_number)  SELECT Eruption Number 
from Eruptions where start year >= 2000
```

Now I want to add the next few columns as well (volcano number, volcano name and start date). But each entry need to of course correspond to the respective eruption number. This is where I am stuck, I am not sure how to do that.
It should be something similar to my code line above, but how does the respective/corresponding volcano number to the eruption number get added.

Thanks

Comment: Possibly answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48690718/sqlite-update-column-from-column-in-another-table

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way to achieve what you want is:
(1) Delete all the rows of `Eruptions_since_2000`:

```
DELETE FROM Eruptions_since_2000;
```

(2) Insert all the rows with all the column values of `Eruptions` to `Eruptions_since_2000`:

```
INSERT INTO Eruptions_since_2000 (Eruption_number, Volcano_Number, Volcano_name, start_date)  
SELECT Eruption_number, Volcano_Number, Volcano_name, start_date 
FROM Eruptions WHERE start_year >= 2000
```

I guess you have managed to calculate `start_year` since you have already used it.
The alternative is this UPDATE statement with the use of [*Row values*](https://www.sqlite.org/rowvalue.html) which are supported from version `3.15.0` of SQLite:

```
update Eruptions_since_2000
set 
  (Volcano_Number, Volcano_name, start_date) = (
    select e.Volcano_Number, e.Volcano_name, e.start_date 
    from Eruptions e 
    where e.Eruption_number = Eruptions_since_2000.Eruption_number
  )
```

If your SQLite version is lower that `3.15.0`, then use this less efficient UPDATE statement:

```
update Eruptions_since_2000 
set 
  Volcano_Number = (select e.Volcano_Number from Eruptions e, whereVolcano_name, e.Eruption_numberstart_date) = Eruptions_since_2000.Eruption_number),
  Volcano_name = (select e.Volcano_name from Eruptions e whereVolcano_Number, e.Eruption_number = Eruptions_since_2000.Eruption_number)Volcano_name,
  start_date = (select e.start_date from Eruptions e where e.Eruption_number = Eruptions_since_2000.Eruption_number)
```